# Differentiate between number and words with Convert to Number

Tags: vba

I am running a vlookup in vba which returns some errors. Some are due to missing values (these should remain #N/A) some are due to the values not being converted to numbers (these need to be fixed). However when I run the below code it converts both numbers and letters into numeric values and returns #VALUE when it should do nothing. I need a way to differentiate between the numbers and any values with a letter in them. In the below example the code should loop through, skip TRD4 and convert 9501 to a number.

```
L26     BW
VR7F    BW
TRD4    #N/A
TRD4    #N/A
9501    #N/A
XDTM    BC
UDDP    TE

For a = 2 To LCell2 Step 1
    v = Cells(a, 9).Value
    If IsError(v) Then
        Cells(a, 8).Value = Evaluate("H" & a)
    End If
Next a
```

Answer (score 1):

It would also help if you included your full code such as what is `v` declared as, is `Cells(a,9)` your listed values such as L26 and what is the formula that is in `H & a`.

Running a quick check with the sample values you have provided you can used `IsNumeric` in your loop to test if a value is made of just numbers or also contains text.  This will work even if the value is stored as text in the cell. To convert a text value to numeric you can use `CInt` or any number of [conversion functions available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx).

So if you want to only evaluate if it's a number and ignore text you can do something similar to

```
For a = 2 to LCell2 Step 1
    If IsNumeric(Cells(a,9)) then
        Cells(a,8).Value = Evaluate("H" & a)
    End If
Next a
```

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work as the numbers are being stored as text, the operation will have to differentiate between any text values containing just numbers and letters with numbers. The purpose of this is to convert the numbers to a numeric value.